# Find records with range including date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 7.1, I have the `token` model with a `validity` date-range attribute.

[image]

Now, I need to find all the tokens valid on a given day (i.e., November 30, 2023), but I'm not sure how to build such a query `Token.where(???)`.

I have found many tutorials and posts explaining the opposite problem: find a record with a date within a given range but nothing about my scenario.

Comment: For anyone interested, not sure if there is a better way but this does the trick `Token.where("validity @> date ?", '2023-11-30')`